# Как скрыть html код через php?

Tags: html, php

Имеется редактор фото на html5 и css3, как скрыть код через php?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под словом "скрыть"? А то народ бросился отвечать о том, как закодировать/зашифровать исходники, а вам может надо скрывать на странице при определенном условии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html и css обрабатывается браузером пользователя. Скрыть его не получится (есть кое-какие вроде заморочки с  шифровкой и кодированием HTML и javascript, но они мало эффективны). Сам PHP можно Zend Guard-ом закодировать.

[Как закодировать HTML и JS с помощью функции charCodeAt Онлайн кодировщик в js Unicode](http://webanet.ucoz.ru/forum/28-167-1)

Comment: На мой взгляд слово генерируется не совсем уместно. Запутывает.

Comment: а "обрабатывается" подойдет? :)

Comment: Если вас удовлетворил ответ, пожалуйста, отметься его верным (алочка под пальчиком вниз). :)